# How can I replace pull switch lights with wireless remote receivers / switches?

Tags: product-recommendation, switch, light-fixture

does anyone have experience with the Lightning Switch or Illumra or recommend any other remote switches for replacing the pull switch light fixtures without having to rewire the house. The tech looks pretty cool, but I want to get a few opinions if anyone here has used them.

Comment: Locking because product specific advice is no longer on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the [Carlon HW2162](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LNMTUA) screw-in wireless remote switch can do the job. I used something similar to replace a pull chain in an attic. Now I can turn on the light at the door, and not have to stumble through the dark to the middle of the attic to find the pull cord.  It will set you back about $30. The installation requires no wiring and takes about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I've never dealt with these companies but it looks simple enough.  I'm around X10 and Z-wave.  On the Lightning Switch it looks like you will need the large or small transmitter and the 120V wire in receiver. [Here](http://www.lightningswitch.com/store.php/lightningonlineorder1867/pg8768/product_dimensions).  The only problem with these is that you will not be able to gang the transmitter with another switch or receptacle.  The Illumra looks like it is about the same, but if you want to gang it with another or a standard switch or receptacle.  [Here](http://www.illumra.com/index.html).

Leviton has a wireless switch similar to this that I have seen.  The factory rep told me it was like the self winding watches, that when you pushed the switch it would you the motion to energize itself, like shaking the watch.  Leviton is made to go with their occupancy sensor so not really a choice for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is ancient, but I just wanted to point out for future readers that the [Illumra](http://illumra.com/products/wireless-light-switches/) and the Leviton wireless light switches are both made by the same manufacturer, and as such, should be the same product. Either company should be able to provide a good solution to a pull switch light. I've been researching this a bit and also found the same light switch in a kit with a controller on Amazon [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012H6QZVC), which is a good option for homeowners, I think.